# How can I get a list of AD user groups along with AD user with Microsoft Graph SDK

Tags: c#, active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

The code:

```
            var users = await graphClient.Users
            .Request()
            .Filter("startswith(userPrincipalName, '" + userPrincipalName + "')")
            .Select(u => new { u.Id, u.OtherMails, u.DisplayName, u.UserPrincipalName, u.MemberOf })
            .GetAsync();
```

returns a null for MemberOf. I know I can do a subsequent:

```
var groups = await graphClient.Users[user.Id].MemberOf.Request().GetAsync();
```

but I'd rather return a Microsoft.Graph.User class type with all the info.

Comment: To my knowledge, you cannot. I do this and I use two queries.

Comment: Hi @Crowcoder, if you get the groups in a subsequent query, can you somehow add them to the retrieved User object?

Comment: You could create your own class with all the properties you want from both results and map the data to instances.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that, doing something like the following but can't get the right code:             var groups = await graphClient.Users[user.Id].MemberOf.Request().GetAsync();

            var memberOf = new User().MemberOf;

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                memberOf.Add(group);
            }

            user.MemberOf = memberOf;

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `memberOf` is not a property but a relationship and you can get the relationship's data by using expand query parameter. See the below API call and its result.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(userPrincipalName,'Shiva@nishantsingh.live')&$select=id, displayName, memberOf&$expand=memberOf`

[image]

So, use the code something like this.

```
var users = await graphClient.Users
            .Request()
            .Filter("startswith(userPrincipalName, '" + userPrincipalName + "')")
            .Select(u => new { u.Id, u.OtherMails, u.DisplayName, u.UserPrincipalName, u.MemberOf })
            .Expand(d => d.memberOf)
            .GetAsync();
```